# Lg plasma tv + ps4?

Tags: ps4

I have an LG plasma TV and I can play PS3 on it perfectly fine. I'm wondering if a ps4 will work fine on it or will it be too powerful for the TV. The TV has 3x HDMI and is about 4-5 years old.

Answer (score 4):

Your TV should be completely fine. The PS4 supports following output resolutions:

- 480p
- 720p
- 1080i
- 1080p

Of course, a TV with HDMI should at the very least support 720p, but if you're particularly paranoid and want to know which modes your TV supports, you can try it out on your PS3. To do this, you need to go to `Settings > Display Settings > Video Output Settings`, select the connection type, then select `Custom`.

The PS3 supports following output resolutions:

- 576p
- 720p
- 1080i
- 1080p

Unless your TV is really, *really* old and doesn't support any resolution other than 576p (not even 480p), then it should support the PS4 just fine.

The only inconvenience you might experience when playing on a resolution below 1080 is if a PS4 game was designed specifically for 1080. In such a case, text and important HUD (Heads-Up Display) elements might be difficult or even impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

The PS4 does support HDMI, so there should be no problem.

The power of the console doesn't really have any effect on what the TV can do, the worst thing that could happen is it wont look any better than the PS3 gameplay (If your TV was already at it's max resolution, but that's pretty unlikely even for an older TV)